# Residue Xvnc process after exiting Windows Remote Desktop Connection to an Ubuntu machine

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop, xrdp

I connected to my server's  Ubuntu 14.04 VM via Windows Remote Desktop Connection.
After logging out of the session I checked the processes running with `top` command in a putty session and saw Xvnc processes still running on the system.
Following command

```
ps -ef | grep Xvnc
```

outputs:

```
zebi2    63444     1  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 Xvnc :10 -geometry 1364x768 -depth 24 -rfbauth /home/zebi2/.vnc/sesman_zebi2_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96
zebi2    64981 37219  0 13:00 pts/16   00:00:00 grep --color=auto Xvnc
```

First line is what I am actually concerned about. I run RDC many times a day and it creates an additional process every time. I don't want to kill the process every time I logout of RDC, also I cannot leave the process since it will increase cpu utilization . Any help or solution is appreciated

Comment: How did you setup / configure the VNC/RDP server? it's probably a matter of adding the appropriate VNC flag (`-once` ) to the session manager ini file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have posted the answer which solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was session cache history which might have been saved previously.

> 1. Unticked 'automatically save session' in 'Session and Startup' in XRDP
>      desktop settings
> 2. Cleared $HOME/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-* (all of the previously
>      saved session data).
> 3. And restarted xrdp service

This link helped
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6580